# Using TFTP on Fedora 22

Tags: linux, fedora, tftp, xinetd, tftpd

I am trying to troubleshoot tftp on my Fedora 22 to see if it is working or not. All I want to do is transfer a file between two systems. The commands I am finding online are not working. All I need is the command and the directory where the files will go on both ends. I get a connection established to the tftp but when I do a `get` it times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tftp server setting can be viewed in /etc/xinetd.d/tftp.

server_args = -s  /tftproot # tftproot is where your tftp  base directory.

Say you tftp server is hostx

From hosty, try this command

*tftp hostx*

> ***tftp   get*** file   # file is any file under  this /tftproot directory.

> tftp quit

*ls -l file*